Is the weak topology on the infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space $T_5$?
I was looking around in pi-base and apparently they don't know whether the weak topology on the infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space is Completely Normal or not (although they know it is $T_4$). Are there any references proving/disproving it, or is there a simple proof/disproof of this fact?

Maybe, an start could be to study if this space is $G_{\delta}$ or not.

@Almanzoris $G_\delta$ in what…? $G_\delta$ only makes sense for a subset of a larger space.

See https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000132.

@Almanzoris Huh, I didn’t know such spaces are just called $G_\delta$. That’s good to know. Thanks!

No problem, you're welcome!

@Almanzoris FYI, there may be some confusion here between "$G_\delta$-set" and "$G_\delta$-space, which are two different things.  When people talk of $G_\delta$", they usually mean a $G_\delta$ set.  But every space is a $G_\delta$ in itself.  That's why I think it's preferable to talk of "$G_\delta$ space" in full.

Alright, thank you for having informed me.

In the article $\aleph_0$-Spaces by Michael, its proven that dual of a Banach space in weak$^*$ topology is an $\aleph_0$-space. Since the property of being an $\aleph_0$-space is hereditary and implies that a space is Lindelof and regular, such spaces are hereditarily Lindelof and regular. This implies they are $T_6$, see this post. In fact, on pi-base we are in the process of adding that this space is an $\aleph_0$-space which will automatically show its $T_6$ as per built-in theorems.

Here is my attempt (see this question):

Definition: Let $X$ be a topological space. A family $\mathcal{N}$ of subsets of $X$ is called a network in $X$ if every open set of $X$ is the union of a subfamily of $\mathcal{N}$.
Note: By definition, in a topological space, a base is a network whose elements are open sets.
Lemma: Let $X$ be a set, and let $\tau$, $\tau'$ be two topologies on $X$ such that $\tau' \subseteq \tau$. If $\mathcal{N}$ is a network for $\tau$, then $\mathcal{N}$ is a network for $\tau'$ too.
Proof:
Let $\mathcal{N}$ be a network for $\tau$ and let $A \in \tau'$. As, $A \in \tau' \subseteq \tau$, then $A$ is the union of a subfamily of $\mathcal{N}$. Hence, $\mathcal{N}$ is a network for $\tau'$.

Answering the question:
Let $(X, \tau')$ be the Weak topology on a separable Hilbert space and let $(X, \tau)$ be the Strong topology on a separable Hilbert space.
$(X, \tau)$ is separable and metrizable, so it is second countable. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a countable base of $(X, \tau)$, $\mathcal{B}$ is a countable network of $(X, \tau)$. As $\tau' \subseteq \tau$, by the Lemma, $\mathcal{B}$ is a countable network of $(X, \tau')$.
Since having a countable network implies hereditarily Lindelöf (see here), $(X, \tau')$ is hereditarily Lindelöf.
As $(X, \tau')$ is hereditarily Lindelöf and regular, then $(X, \tau')$ is perfectly normal. And, as $(X, \tau')$ is also $T_0$, then $(X, \tau')$ is $T_6$, so also $T_5$.

I've also answered this here. Note that I wasn't aware of this question.

Interesting. I didn't know that you had asked that question and that you had answered it too. Thanks for letting me know.
